# ambiguous column name when using conditions on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some issues where, when working with a 3rd party's application's database I have to do some weird joins where I am often joining to a sort of catch-all table for multiple different kinds of objects.
As such I create has_many or has_one associations that have conditions clauses.
Problem is if I try to join two of these associations in the same query I get an "ambiguous column name", and rightly so since the same column is called in the condition for both associations.

Is there a way around this issue.  Would be nice if I could tell the association to always prefix with the join name.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using that generates that error? It may also help telling us what DB you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the conditions clause, you can assert your table name is present like this:

```
has_many :x_models, :conditions => {attribute: some_value}
has_many :y_models, :conditions => {attribute: some_value}
```

EDITED

Maybe this is what you are tooking for.

Comment: My issue is I need the conditions to be on the association itself, not in the where.

Comment: But the table usually gets aliased to a different name depending on how you call it, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Edited to use hash condition instead